# Python no output from class method

Tags: python

When I call the `displaycount` method of my list subclass, I get no output. What is the problem?

```
class mylist(list):

    def _init_(self,name,age):
        list._init_(self, years)
        self.name = name;
        self.age = age;

    def displaycount(self):
        print "total employees %d" % self.name
        emp1 = mylist('lada', 20)
        emp1.displaycount()
```

Comment: did you call displaycount?

Comment: You have to instantiate the `mylist` class for it's `__init__` method to be called. You'll also have to call the `displaycount` and perhaps fix your indentation

Comment: It looks like you are calling `displaycount` only inside itself, which might cause infinite recursion if you actually call it once from outside ...

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "blank result"? Could you should the calling code, and review your indentation - it looks like `displaycount` is nested inside `_init_` (which has the wrong number of underscores!)

Comment: @user3 so you mean  here am the calling the mylist inside the function displaycount ?...it must be outside the function right ?

Comment: @icedtrees - just so you know, your edit (while correct) might just have solved the OP's problem. In the future, please refrain from making edits to any code blocks without first confirming with the OP.

Comment: @Lix Alright, my bad. But the code does not even run if `__init__` is not indented, so I figured it was a typo on the poster's part, rather than their actual problem.

Comment: @icedtrees - and you very well might be correct. But it's always safer to confim this with the OP - otherwise you might render the question invalid by accidentally fixing the problem :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. `'_init_' != '__init__'`;
2. Where is `years` defined?
3. Given that `self.name` is a string, what do you think `"total employees %d" % self.name` will do?
4. `displaycount` currently recursively calls itself on a new `mylist` instance.

Perhaps you mean:

```
class mylist(list):

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super(mylist, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def displaycount(self):
        print "total employees {0}".format(self.age)


emp1 = mylist('lada', 20)
emp1.displaycount()
```

Comment: @jonrshape so while calling we must use __init__ instead of _init_ right ? and i need to define this.years also right ?

Comment: @user3517846 I don't have enough information about what you're doing - I have added a suggested implementation

Comment: why you called  super(mylist, self).__init__() isntead of         list._init_(self, years). i think         list._init_(self, years) is also correct..

Comment: `list.__init__(self)` - two underscores, and you still haven't defined `years`

Comment: yeah i got and i have one doubt too ..is         super(mylist, self).__init__() and list.__init__(self) do the same function ?

Comment: @user3517846 yes, if you stick with `mylist(list)`, but using `super` means you don't have to change `mylist.__init__` if you change what it inherits from

Comment: @user3517846 I get a `TypeError`, not an `AttributeError`, because an `int` like `age` isn't iterable and therefore isn't an appropriate argument to `list.__init__`. You get the same error with `super(mylist, self).__init__(age)`. I can't tell you if it's necessary, I still don't know enough about what you're trying to do!